# windows azure media services The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error

Tags: azure, service, media, internal

I am getting **The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error** when trying to upload large Asset/Video of around 25MB. 
Below is the exact error

```
"innerException": {
    "message": "An error has occurred.",
    "exceptionMessage": "One or more errors occurred.",
    "exceptionType": "System.AggregateException",
    "stackTrace": "   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)\r\n   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MediaServices.Client.AssetFileData.<>c__DisplayClass24.<UploadAsync>b__1c(Task`1 t)\r\n   at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationTaskFromResultTask`1.InnerInvoke()\r\n   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()",
    "innerException": {
    "message": "An error has occurred.",
    "exceptionMessage": "One or more errors occurred.",
    "exceptionType": "System.AggregateException",
    "stackTrace": "   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MediaServices.Client.TaskExtensions.ThrowIfFaulted(Task task, Action faultedCallback)\r\n   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MediaServices.Client.AssetFileData.PostUploadAction(Task task, String path, FileEncryption fileEncryption, AssetCreationOptions assetCreationOptions, CancellationToken token)\r\n   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MediaServices.Client.AssetFileData.<>c__DisplayClassd.<UploadAsync>b__a(Task ts)\r\n   at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationTaskFromTask.InnerInvoke()\r\n   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()",
    "innerException": {
        "message": "An error has occurred.",
        "exceptionMessage": "The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.",
        "exceptionType": "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException",
        "stackTrace": "   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Util.StorageAsyncResult`1.End()\r\n   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MediaServices.Client.BlobUploader.<>c__DisplayClassd.<EndPutBlock>b__c()\r\n   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MediaServices.Client.BlobTransferBase.IsActionSuccessfulOrRetryable(BlobTransferContext transferContext, Action action)",
        "innerException": {
        "message": "An error has occurred.",
        "exceptionMessage": "The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.",
        "exceptionType": "System.Net.WebException",
        "stackTrace": "   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Shared.Protocol.HttpResponseParsers.ProcessExpectedStatusCodeNoException[T](HttpStatusCode expectedStatusCode, HttpStatusCode actualStatusCode, T retVal, StorageCommandBase`1 cmd, Exception ex)\r\n   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlockBlob.<PutBlockImpl>b__3e(RESTCommand`1 cmd, HttpWebResponse resp, Exception ex, OperationContext ctx)\r\n   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.EndGetResponse[T](IAsyncResult getResponseResult)"
        }
    }
```

Comment: how did you get to this error. Providing code parts that cause the error is the first thing to post when asking question on SO. Also, does it happen with that particular file, or with all files that are over XXX MB in lenght? Does your code work with smaller files, or fails there too?

Comment: Hi, whats your account name/Subscription ID?

Comment: Hi, We take a look at our log for your subscription ID: There are no REST Request failures with Storage Exception or Internal Server Errors for Asset POST in our Logs in the last 24 hours for this account id. Therefore, I believe there maybe some portal update going on last night. Could you try to upload your file again?

Comment: I tried this several times. Still getting the same error

Comment: I got the same issue today using a command line tool I wrote to upload single 4-6MB blobs to Azure, using storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient().GetContainerReference(container).GetBlockBlobReference(blobName).UploadFromFile(path, FileMode.Open), Azure.Storage dll version 3.0.3.0. Been working fine for months. Switched to AzCopy instead, which seems to work.